# Deep error on socket.py: TypeError: a float is required

Tags: python, sockets, celery, typeerror, twilio

I wrote a feature to run a task asynchronously via celery, tested it locally and it's all good. Shipped to my staging environment and when the celery tries to consume the tasks it fails with the following traceback.

I'm not even sure how I can go about debugging this error, as it's being called by celery, and happening deep in the python standard lib. Any ideas?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/hypnos-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 238, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/hypnos-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 416, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Hypnos/hypnos/recs_jobber/tasks.py", line 5, in send_sms_action
    msg = twilio_client.sms.messages.create(body = sms_action.body, to=sms_action.to_number, from_=TW_NUMBER)
  File "/home/ubuntu/hypnos-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twilio/rest/resources/sms_messages.py", line 167, in create
    return self.create_instance(kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/hypnos-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twilio/rest/resources/base.py", line 352, in create_instance
    data=transform_params(body))
  File "/home/ubuntu/hypnos-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twilio/rest/resources/base.py", line 204, in request
    resp = make_twilio_request(method, uri, auth=self.auth, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/hypnos-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twilio/rest/resources/base.py", line 129, in make_twilio_request
    resp = make_request(method, uri, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/hypnos-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twilio/rest/resources/base.py", line 101, in make_request
    resp, content = http.request(url, method, headers=headers, body=data)
  File "/home/ubuntu/hypnos-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1570, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/home/ubuntu/hypnos-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1317, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/home/ubuntu/hypnos-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1252, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/ubuntu/hypnos-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1017, in connect
    sock.settimeout(self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
TypeError: a float is required
```

Used Celery's rdb to get into the frame and seems that the socket timeout is not set.

```
(Pdb) self.timeout
<Unset Timeout Value>
```

Any ideas how I might solve this? The error is flowing from Twilio -> httplib2 -> socket.py which is a wrapper to _socket. This is over my head and not sure even how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Twilio's lib sets timeout to:

```
class _UnsetTimeoutKls(object):
    """ A sentinel for an unset timeout. Defaults to the system timeout. """
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Unset Timeout Value>'


# None has special meaning for timeouts, so we use this sigil to indicate
# that we don't care
UNSET_TIMEOUT = _UnsetTimeoutKls()
```

So something must be happening in between instantiating a `TwilioRestClient` and the actual socket call that is evaluating that `_UnsetTimeoutKls` to something different than None.

Setting timeout to None when initialising `TwilioRestClient` seems to fix the error:

```
self.client = TwilioRestClient(TWILIO_SID,
                    TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN,
                    timeout=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what's going on:

- You're telling the Twilio library to create an SMS message.
- Twilio goes over to `httplib` to connect to the Twilio servers.
- `httplib`, while connecting to the Twilio servers, sets the timeout of a socket.

The only problem is that for some reason, `self.timeout` in the penultimate stack frame is not a `float` as required. You may want to try running your application under the Python debugger, e.g.:

```
python -m pdb myapp.py
```

You'll get to a prompt from which you can type `run` to run your application. Once the error occurs, it should drop you back to the prompt. You should then be able to type `up` until you get to the offending frame and see what `self.timeout` is. You may then want to look around to see where `self.timeout` is getting set to that, and why. You should then be able to resolve the issue by fixing that.